# Data taken from survey where survey-takers self report a continous variable

Tags: self-study, dataset, survey, bias

I have a problem with some health data that I'm trying to analyze. The main issue originates from a census variable is derived from self reported times. The variable is sleep duration, which is derived from the hour reported at which the survey-taker goes to sleep, and the hour at which they wake up. The documentation says that the value is then rounded to the nearest half hour. Here is a histogram of the data:

[image]

Because of the self-reported nature of the data, and the rounding, there seems to be a bias towards whole hour values over half hour values. Intuitively, I'd expect this variable to be distributed normally. I want to somehow correct this bias, or at least artificially modify the data so it is distributed rationally.

I do not mind modifying the data, as it having a sensible distribution is more important than accurately mirroring the survey data for me. I tried adding Gaussian noise with SD=0.5, and I got the following histogram:

[image]

This looks more like what I would expect the actual values to look like. However, I don't know if there is a better or standard way to correct/analyze data with this kind of bias. If there is, or if there is some flaw in my reasoning, please let me know.

Comment: This seems like a VERY bad idea to me.  But what are you going to do with the sleep variable? Is it a DV in a regression?  An IV? Part of a cluster analysis? Or what?

Comment: "*having a sensible distribution is more important than accurately mirroring the survey data for me*" Why?

Comment: I don't actually care about the data all that much. It's for a statistics class, and I've spoken with my professor about this issue. She doesn't mind if the data is partially artificial. The assignment is more about applying statistical methods rather than doing a super rigorous analysis.

Comment: I'm going to do a multiple regression with sleep as the DV

Comment: I will also probably do some kind of two sample hypothesis test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> I want to somehow correct this bias, or at least artificially modify the data so it is distributed rationally.

and also:

> I'm going to do a multiple regression with sleep as the DV

In that case do NOT "modify" the data. Just use sleep as it exists in the dataset as your outcome. Then do the usual regression diagnostics. Modifying the data seems to be a very bad idea as mentioned by Peter Flom in the comment to the question. Adding noise to your outcome variable does not make any sense to me. Also, bear in mind that the histograms of data can look very strange due to the binning levels you use. For example:

```
set.seed(101)
hist(rnorm(100),breaks = 20)
```

produces this:
[image]

Comment: I also need to fit a distribution. I'm sorry I failed to mention that.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, does it ?

Comment: I need to do a goodness of fit test, and I suspect that will not go well.

Comment: You mean a goodness of fit test of your model fit ? That's just part of the usual regression diagnostics. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: No, goodness of fit for the distribution I fit to the data.

Comment: Fine. Go ahead. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you are for some reason required by teachers to have a normally distributed dependent variable for a regression analysis, and it doesn't have to be real data, why not just generate the variable altogether?

Comment: The specific issue, is that I have selected a real dataset, and the professor wants us to fit a distribution to our primary variable. She does want a real dataset, but it's late into the semester, and I've only just now realized the poor quality of the data. I've spoken with the professor, and she said that I could add noise to this variable, or select a different dataset.

Comment: So go ahead and fit the distribution to the data. It may or may not be a good fit. Are you marked based on how well it fits ? I would doubt that. I would think the teacher just wants to see that you know how to fit a distribution to data and interpret the finding. As for the regression model, none of that changes my advice. But it seem that you already know what you want to do, so it makes me wonder why are you asking a question here? I think you've been told by several people that what you want to do is not a good idea, but you seem to intent on doing what you want despite best advice.

Comment: It's honestly a bad stats class, but whatever. The professor requires us to fit some distribution to the data that passes the goodness of fit test. I ended up randomly sampling the data to artificially reduce the test's power. The sampled data passes the test without modification (with n=100).

Comment: Sounds like you found a solution that works for the class, but I was wondering if it would have worked to code the original variable less accurately by always rounding to the full hour?